# Working with XML in Java: fluent XSD and no need to parse

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Does anyone know the solution for working with XML in Java that meets these requirements?

- Ability to fluently define XML schema (with no XSD)
- Ability to work with XML data via Java standard types: if I say that this attribute of this tag is an integer, I'd like to be able to read and write it as `int`, without parsing and converting it to string manually.

The ideal solution is like this:

```
class MyXmlData { 
  @Bind("...xpath here...", Bind.Required)
  public Integer numberOfPersons; // required, integer

  @Bind("...xpath here...")
  public String title; // optional 
}

try { // throws, if required fields are not present
  MyXmlData data = MagicXml.read(MyXmlData.class, "1.xml");

  // at this point data.numberOfPersons is never null and
  // title may be null

  int myNumOfPersons = data.numberOfPersons; // here we go
}
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want here - what do you mean by "fluently"? What do you mean by "no need to parse"?  You more or less have to use XSD's if you want a schema. If you want to process xml, you *have* to parse it, perhaps by using a library.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the terms you're using. _fluently_ define XSD? _no need to parse_? Other than that my first impression is to go for JAXB. (Edit: @Arafangion You saw the weird terminology too :-)

Comment: *fluently* like in *Fluent NHibernate*, you should probably read about *fluent interfaces*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).  Our `@XmlPath` annotation is similar to the `@Bind` annotation that you are looking for:

```
package blog.geocode;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement(name="kml")
@XmlType(propOrder={"country", "state", "city", "street", "postalCode"})
public class Address {

    @XmlPath("Response/Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:SubAdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:Thoroughfare/ns:ThoroughfareName/text()")
    private String street;

    @XmlPath("Response/Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:SubAdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:LocalityName/text()")
    private String city;

    @XmlPath("Response/Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:AdministrativeAreaName/text()")
    private String state;

    @XmlPath("Response/Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:CountryNameCode/text()")
    private String country;

    @XmlPath("Response/Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:SubAdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:PostalCode/ns:PostalCodeNumber/text()")
    private String postalCode;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: Darn, should have seen this question sooner. I wanted to time how long Doughan took to suggest MOXy :D Seems like the perfect fit for the asker.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan: Thanks, that works. Another question for now is - how do I mark any of these fields optional/required. The problem is, empty xml tags are treated as 0 for ints and empty string for strings. How do I required some tags to be non-empty?

Comment: @loki2302 - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192619/how-do-i-mark-fields-as-required-optional-when-reading-xml-with-moxy/7193342#7193342

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries, e.g. JAXB, JiBX and so on. See http://jvalentino.blogspot.com/2008/06/easiest-java-xml-binding.html

Comment: Also OXM. http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html